# How can I iterate and print all elements of a Menu (not objects or elements on scene)?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, interface, command-line

I'm having this little problem that is already costing me more than 24h of research hahaha. I didn't find the answer in any forum and I can't solve it myself in blender.

My question is quite simple.
**I want to iterate over the elements of a certain Menu in blender and print all their values.** What is easy for me to do with objects in the scene but with these values of the Menus seems to be quite different.
I've already tested all the available methods and none of them return the values, just the data structure, the menu class, context, append, remove, etc. **I specifically need to return the values that a Menu has.**

I'm putting a print of an example Menu, the View Menu of the 3DViewport (`bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view`), I would like to get a list of these Menu values.
**Ex. ('Tollbar', 'Sidebar', 'Tool_Setting', ...).**

**Thanks in advance for the help!**

[image]

Comment: I think Blender's Python API does not have such a functionality. Because why would it? Why do you need this? What are you trying to do? Maybe if you share more context someone may be able to suggest other solutions.

Comment: Hello @MartynasŽiemys thank you for your attention and the time to make this observation here.  I also thought that blender might not have this functionality, however, I'm still not completely convinced of that, because it still doesn't make much sense not to have it (or I still don't understand some specific data manipulation detail by the software, sorry btw :) ), anyways, actually I still don't have a specific application (yet), I'm just doing some tests and looking for a better understanding of how Blender organizes and manipulates this data.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Continuing my reasoning on the previous comment. My question is based on the following premise: blender can apply methods like append, pop, prepends, etc.  to already existing menus, so it is to be imagined that these menus store these options in some kind of list, array or structures of that type. It's from here that I started my research and I couldn't find a way to access these 'possible lists', that's why I posted this question here, in the hope that someone has already done it somehow and can give me a light.

Comment: I am not a professional programmer and no expert in Python in general, but I am quite familiar with Blender's Python API. There are no tools in it for this as far as I know. Those 'possible lists' are just Python scripts that define Blender's UI as far as I know.  The VIEW3D_MT_view menu is defined in `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_view3d.py` at line 1210 for example. You will see items are often sensitive to various conditions and context if you have a look at the files. I think they just don't work the way you expect in this case.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Thanks again man. I took a look at this file you pointed, it's really huge hahaha, however, I think it's very promising for my mission to understand between the lines of how Blender is built and how it handles data and structures. There are several other scripts in these folders, I'll spend a few hours studying them, but I believe it will be worth it for my learning. Thanks a lot for the help :)